# 404 not found laravel routing

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

what's wrong with my routes? it can't redirect to my *edit-info* form inside *InfosController*

**web.php**

```
route::get('/info-admin/{$info}/edit','InfosController@edit');
```

**info-admin.blade.php**

```
@foreach ( $info as $infos )
                <tr>
                <th scope="row" class="align-middle">{{ $loop->iteration }}</th>
                <td class="align-middle">{{ $infos->judul }}</td>
                <td class="align-middle">{{ $infos->konten }}</td>
                <td class="align-middle">{{ $infos->image }}</td>
                <td class="align-middle">{{ $infos->created_at }}</td>
                <td class="align-middle">{{ $infos->Updated_at }}</td>
                <td class="align-middle form">
                <a href="/info-admin/{{ $infos->id }}/edit"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-info mb-3">Edit</button></a>
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('infos.destroy', [$infos->id]) }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Hapus</button>
                    </form>
               </td>
           </tr>
@endforeach
```

**InfosController@edit**

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        return view('admin.edit-info');
    }
```

what did I do wrong, why laravel can't find my routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You route is defined wrong.

```
route::get('/info-admin/{$info}/edit','InfosController@edit');
```

Should be without `$` and name the route for easier linking.

```
route::get('/info-admin/{info}/edit','InfosController@edit')->name('infos.edit');
```

Instead of hard coding it, use route as you do with destroy on the edit link too.

```
<a href="{{ route('infos.edit', [$infos->id]) }}">
```

To check if you routes are defined correctly, try running in the project.

```
php artisan route:list
```

Comment: hello i want to ask again, why it's show me the undefined variables when i want to submit the update? i already edited my question

Comment: You can't just update the whole original question as the answer will become irrelevant. Create a new one and i will happily look at it, and link it here :)

Comment: well i need to wait 90min thats why i tried to edit the whole thing

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways by which you can accomplish this:

```
<a href="{{action('InfosController@edit',$infos->id)}}">Edit</a>
<a href="{{ url('/info-admin/{$info}/edit'') }}">Edit</a>
```